High school kinematics problem

From a town, cars start at regular intervals of 30 seconds and run towards, another town with a constant speed of 60km/h. At some point of time, all the cars simultaneously have to reduce their speeds to 40km/h due to bad weather conditions. What will be the time interval between arrivals of the cars at the second town during the bad weather?

I have done this algebraically but want to do this graphically but could not .

As far as I can tell, the arrival interval is always 30 seconds, except for the one interval that is occurring at the time the bad weather strikes (cars leaving 30s apart will arrive 30s apart when moving at any constant non-zero speed). It's not clear what is meant by "during" bad weather, it's different between when it strikes and as it continues.

So for the 1st car, you have a speed-time graph as follows:

where $t_{\rm D1}=0$ is the departure time, and $t_{\rm A1}$ is the arrival time, whilst traveling at $v_{\rm F}=60$ (fast) speed at first, and transitioning to $v_{\rm S}=40$ (slow) speed at some fixed time $T$ when the weather changes.
The total distance traveled is fixed as $L = x_{\rm 1F} + x_{\rm 1S}$ and corresponds to the two areas of the two rectangles shaded above.
Now the 2nd car, which leaves after a delay of $t_{\rm D2}=30$ and arrives at the unknown time of $t_{\rm A2}$, has a graph as follows:

The graph goes through the same transition from fast to slow at the same time $T$ as above.
The total distance traveled is fixed $L = x_{\rm 2F} + x_{\rm 2S}$ and so this is going to guide you to find the arrival delay of the second car, as the area of the rectangle that needs to be added to the end, to compensate for the are of the rectangle which is missing from the start due to the delay between cars.

PS. You must convert all values into consistent units for the result to make sense.

Thanks Mr John .
